# How to accumulate color when rendering to texture?

Tags: graphics, directx, shader, lighting

I am trying to implement deferred shading using MRTs. For that, I need to accumulate the color and the normals in two rendering targets. I defined two `R32G32B32A32` textures for that end.

The pixel buffer outputs to both rendering targets. However, how do I instruct it to **accumulate** the values, rather than replace or blend them?

I tried defining the following blending state:

```
blendState.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable =            TRUE;
blendState.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask =  D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
blendState.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend =               D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendState.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend =              D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendState.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp =                D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendState.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha =          D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendState.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha =         D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendState.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha =           D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendState.RenderTarget[1].BlendEnable =            TRUE;
blendState.RenderTarget[1].RenderTargetWriteMask =  D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
blendState.RenderTarget[1].SrcBlend =               D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendState.RenderTarget[1].DestBlend =              D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendState.RenderTarget[1].BlendOp =                D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendState.RenderTarget[1].SrcBlendAlpha =          D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendState.RenderTarget[1].DestBlendAlpha =         D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendState.RenderTarget[1].BlendOpAlpha =           D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
```

But the values I'm getting are weird.

Please help! How do I accumulate values?

Comment: ..do you mean 'how to add colors'?

Comment: In a sense, yes. I want them to accumulate on the render target so I can use them in the next pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement deferred shading you technically should not accumulate either normals or color, since when you will do the deferred processing (light calculations/occlusion/depth of field...), each MRT texture pixel(color/depth/normals), need to represent the closest object from the view point.

So only setting a depth state to read/write and comparison function to either less/lessequal, with no blend at all should be the way to go.

Comment: The problem is I also have many transparent objects. This is why I need to accumulate the colors.

Comment: Accumulating the colors/normals as additive will not solve transparency. Since you light calculations rely on normals, adding normals between two object does not result in any type of defined behavious. It's also the same for colors, Since your object diffuse term will become invalid. There's different techniques for transparency (multiple gbuffer per layers, or forward pass for transparent)

Comment: Here are a few links for help also: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch19.html , http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=75, http://www4.atword.jp/cathy39/category/direct3d11/oit-direct3d11/

Comment: I'll check them out, but I have already read them both. It might do me good to implement OIT. Thanks